# How to fix my sidebar appearing at the bottom of the document on smaller resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Hello the code below generates a Bootstrap page with some lorem text and a sidebar however when the size of the browser window gets smaller it appears at the bottom of the document not on the side and when on very small resolutions it becomes hidden which is intended how do I make it appear at the side when on medium resolutions?

```css
.sidebar-user-box {
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Page style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">

    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Social Media Site</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Social Media Site</a>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 col-xs-9 pt-3 px-4">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: blue;"></div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: white;">
                            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit ut necessitatibus accusamus temporibus magni recusandae tempore, provident consectetur commodi quas cum? Rerum, beatae sed odit quia nobis itaque possimus illo.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: darkblue;"></div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: gray;">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil cupiditate repellendus et iusto voluptatem, reprehenderit laudantium qui a dolore dolorum? Perspiciatis voluptates eaque quas architecto cum earum nemo voluptate
                                in?
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="background-color: darkblue;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>

            <nav class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 d-none d-sm-block d-md-block bg-dark sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item sidebar-user-box" id="1">
                            <span id="slider-username">User</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item sidebar-user-box" id="2">
                            <span id="slider-username">User (2)</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *hide* it on on small, remove the `d-sm-block`..

```
    <nav class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 d-none d-md-block bg-dark sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-sticky">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item sidebar-user-box" id="1">
                    <span id="slider-username">User</span>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item sidebar-user-box" id="2">
                    <span id="slider-username">User (2)</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

If you want to *show* it on the side on small, change the outer column breakpoints from  `col-md-*` to `col-sm-*`..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <main role="main" class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <nav class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 d-none d-sm-block bg-dark sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item sidebar-user-box" id="1">
                        <span id="slider-username">User</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item sidebar-user-box" id="2">
                        <span id="slider-username">User (2)</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/WyZu1eBAfQ

Note: There is no `-xs-` infix in Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 5 so the `col-xs-*` classes are doing nothing. Also, jQuery is not needed for Bootstrap 5.

Comment: but I still want it to be on the side at that resolution just not on the bottom.

Comment: Change the outer column breakpoints from `col-md-*` to `col-sm-*`. I update the demo and answer.